# Spotify Simple Player example and libspotify

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, spotify, cocoalibspotify-2.0

I have downloaded libspotify for iOS programming and I'm trying to run the Simple Player example. However, I keep getting the following error:

`Command /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/libtool failed with exit code 1"`

Screenshots can be found [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HfngU.png) and [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HfngU.png#1)

This is the first time I have tried to use any framework that didn't come with XCode, so I am fairly lost at this. I have an application key from developer.spotify.com, but I am unsure of how to add it to my project or the simple player example. Unfortunately, I don't seem to be able to follow the documentation available online very well. Any help would be very useful.

Answer (score 1):

That screenshot sounds like you've got a broken copy of libspotify for some reason. You should delete the whole repo, check it out cleanly from GitHub and try again.

Comment: thank you for the note and taking the time to respond. I did download a new copy, and the error encountered before is gone.
           however, I am still unsure of how exactly to add the appkey to the simple player project to get that to run. I'm sure it is something simple that I am just missing, but I have no clue.     Unfortunately, all my searches for anything similar to spotify appkey and xcode don't provide instructions on how to actually add it. 

Any further help on this is greatly appreciated, as after i finally get the sample working I will hopefully be able to figure this stuff out

Comment: 1) Put the appkey.c file in the same directory as the source files for that sample project, next to the AppDelegate.m files. 2) Find the line in the project that's triggering the error, which is normally in AppDelegate.m. It says "#error Add your appkey then remove this error". Remove that line. Push build.

Comment: I apologize for being a pain in the butt on this, but I am getting closer... and thanks for the continued help...

Now that i have the appkey installed, on the "Simple Player" I am back to a fail with exit code 1 (different than before).   http://imgur.com/AUDra    . I also tried the "guess the intro" app, which did NOT fail, but would not build anything to my ipad simulator... am I still using a bad copy? If so, could you please link to where I can download a good copy?

Comment: Don't add the file to the Xcode project, it only needs to be on disk.

Comment: I swear I feel dumber every time I write on here... I'm not sure which file you are referring to. If I were to start from scratch, and try to run the simple player, I would take the following steps (maybe I am missing something obvious)
1) download file from [here](https://github.com/spotify/cocoalibspotify/downloads)   
2) unzip  
3) open "simple player"  
4) add my appkey / delete error line of code   
5) run app .....
am I missing something here? Once again, thanks for your help. I just want to run the sample app and it is killing me!!

Comment: The appkey file. It shouldn't be in the Xcode project, only on disk.